# Pass argument in nested event handler

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, event-handling

I'm using Highcharts to display an interactive map with custom countries and I need to activate the drilldown feature, i.e. clicking on a country to zoom in on another map with internal states of that country.

The way to go on about this in angular is to add a drilldown event handler to a chartOptions object, load the map data within and then call a function to add the map data as drilldown in the chart.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      events: {
        drilldown(e) {
          // At this point "this" is a Highcharts.MapChart object.
          const chart = this as any;
          const mapKey = `countries/ca/${e.point.drilldown}-all`;
          const mapData = require(`@highcharts/map-collection/${mapKey}.geo.json`);
          const provinceData = Highcharts.geojson(mapData);
          // Filling map data with meaningless values becaus it's just an example.
          provinceData.forEach((el: any, i) => { el.value = i; });

          // Here's the key, the Highcharts.MapChart object is required to add the new map data.
          chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, { name: e.point.name, data: provinceData });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, since I'm not using one of the provided map data from Highcharts but custom map data generated from an SVG file and located in a mongo db, which is loaded from the database on startup and stored in a property of my MapComonent, I need to access that property using "this" in the scope of the component within the event handler function.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  private drilldownData: Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions = { ... };
  public chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      events: {
        // Here "this" is of course in the scope of the MapComponent.
        drilldown: this.handleDrilldown
      }
    }
  }

  private handleDrilldown(e: Highcharts.DrilldownEventObject): void {
    // At this point "this" is a Highcharts.MapChart object.
    let chart = this as any;
    // Now, of course, the drilldownData is undefined because "this" required here is not the MapComponent.
    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, { name: e.point.name, data: this.drilldownData });
  }
}
```

I've tried calling the drilldown as `drilldown: event => this.handleDrilldown(event)` but then "this" inside the handleDrilldown is the MapComponent and I have no way of getting to the Highcharts.MapChart object. The same applies with `drilldown: this.handleDrilldown.bind(this)` which overwrites the internal scope to the MapComponent's. `drilldown: function(event) { this.handleDrilldown(event) }` of course won't work either, because now "this" inside the function already is the Highcharts.MapChart object and thus doesn't have the handleDrilldown method. Is there a way for me to somehow pass the drilldownData into the event handler in this constellation while maintaining the scope of the Highcharts.MapChart inside of the event handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIFE structure to be able to use 'double' this:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            drilldown: (function(MapComponent) {
                return function(e) {
                    console.log(MapComponent, this);
                }
            })(this)
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zputgf1q/

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately Typescript complains about: `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.` for the inner this and I have no idea how to fix this besides maybe disabling strict mode, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Hi @Otto Abnormalverbraucher, You need to add a type for `this`, example: `return function(this: Highcharts.Chart){...}`

Comment: But I already have `return function(e: any)`. `this` doesn't appear here. Where do I put the type definition for `this`?

Comment: You can type it in this way: `return function(this: Highcharts.Chart, e: any)`